# Express wildcard route and webpack

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, webpack

I'm building a MEAN application utilising webpack and I've encountered a strange bug.

I have the following wildcard route to serve a single HTML file which will then let angular do all of the heavy lifting:

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./app/www/index.html');
});
```

This route effects the loading of my webpack app.js and inside assets/app.js (in the browser) I see the contents of index.html.

If change the wildcard route to `app.get('/')` then everything loads fine.